# How can I integrate a Gaussian function with a combination of Chebyshev polynomials?

Tags: integration, gaussian

The Mathematica code for the integration of Gaussian function with Chebyshev polynomial is

```
sigma = 1.0;
(1./(Sqrt[2*pi]*sigma))*Integrate[Exp[-(x^2)/(2*sigma^2)]*Cos[n*ArcCos[x]],{-inf,inf}]
```

But, unfortunately, the Mathematica software was unable to integrate.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$C_n=(2\pi)^{-1/2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\cos[n\,{\rm arccos}\,(x)]\,dx$$

$C_n=0$ for odd $n$, and for even $n$ it equals an integer:

$C_0=1$, $C_2=1$, $C_4=17$, $C_6=353$, $C_8=10049$, $C_{10}=365089$, $C_{12}=16157329$, $C_{14}=843550273$,...

No closed form expression for all $n$ that I am aware of, but there might well be one. (I checked that the series of integers does not give a match on [OEIS](http://oeis.org).) The generating function

$$F(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n t^n=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-x^2/2} (1-t x)}{t^2-2 t x+1}\,dx$$
has a closed-form answer (in terms of the error function), but this does not readily yield the $C_n$'s.

Comment: Thank You. Carlo Beenkerk I am looking for a general expression.
Mathematica eventually solves for some value of n.. but not for all.

Comment: Interesting. Any reason why the $C_n$ should be integer?

Comment: Maybe due to the integer coefficient of Chebyshev polynomials

Comment: Ops of course. I forgot that your variance is an integer (one).